# Chapter 2.3 Exercise 14 - Metric Spaces: A Companion to Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove one of the questions in *Metric Spaces: A Companion to Analysis*, Chapter 2.3, Exercise 14, but am trying to make sure I am understanding this correctly.

> 14. Let $X$ be a metric space and let $A$ be closed in $X$. Suppose that the function $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \partial A$. Show that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ by setting $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A^c$.

I thought maybe in order to prove this, we need to use the definition of continuous in metric spaces:

> For $x \in X$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for every open neighbourhood $V$ containing $f(x)$, there exists a open neighbourhood $U$ containing $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$.

My attempt is as follows:

*Proof.* If $x \in X$ is arbitrary, then we have three cases to consider. If $x \in \partial A$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \partial A$, and as $\partial A \subset X$, $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \partial A$ as well and thus, $g$ is also continuous. Next if $x \in A^c$, similar to the above, $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in A^c$ and therefore is continuous. The last case we would have to consider is if $x \in A$. If $x \in A$, since $f$ is continuous, then for every open neighbourhood $V$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ containing $x \in A$ such that $f|_A(U) \subset V$. But since $f|_A(U) \subset g(U) \subset V$, we have $g(U) \subset V$ and therefore, $g$ is also continuous. Therefore, $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Is this proof correct? If there's any details that are missing what should I include?

Comment: What is your definition of a neighbourhood? Usually they are either open themselves or contain an open neighbourhood, and so your use of $\partial A$ as the neighbourhood in the first case may not be sufficient :)!

Comment: @OsamaGhani Sorry, I meant open neighbourhood! But if $A$ is closed, wouldn't that also mean that there are points on the boundary, in which case $x \in \partial A$ and so $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \partial A$?

Comment: Right! Typically $\partial A$ isn't open (think about the boundary of a disk!). But the issue might be because you're not looking at an open neighbourhood $V$ around $0$!

Comment: So if $\partial A$ is not open, but $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \partial A$, it would still be continuous, but instead of using the open neighbourhood definition, would I have to use the closed neighborhood definition?

Comment: If you have one then that would definitely help here! If you also know the general continuity definition (e.g. $U$ is open $\implies f^{-1}(U)$ is open) might make it easier too but really any of the definitions would work!